# How to autostart and loop a movie...?

Tags: mediaelement.js

...and showing nothing than the movie itself? This should work with *.mp4, *.ogv *webm and the flash fallback

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are using. But here is an article that explains tags converning videos.  Search for "autostart"

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlvideocodes.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code to start the movie automatically:

```
var settings = {};

settings.success = function( mediaElement, domObject ) {
   // if using the Flash player, we need to listen to the `canplay` event
   if (mediaElement.pluginType == 'flash') {
      mediaElement.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
         // Player is ready
         mediaElement.play();
      }, false);
   } else {
         // call the play method
         mediaElement.play();
      }
   };

// the controls, we don't want any of them
settings.features = [];

$( 'video' ).mediaelementplayer( settings );
```

And here is the CSS code to hide the play icon in the center of the movie window:

```
.mejs-overlay-button {
    display: none;
}
```